# Duplicate Iterable and Collection Hamcrest matchers

Tags: java, hamcrest

I see that Hamcrest for Java defines some matchers for both `Iterable`s and `Collection`s that perform the same matching.

For example, `iterableWithSize()` in `IsIterableWithSize` and `hasSize()` in `IsCollectionWithSize`. To my knowledge, the latter isn't necessary since any collection can be passed to the `Iterable` version.

Is there any technical explanation to design an API such that `Iterable`s and `Collection`s are handled separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Collection` interface includes methods that speed up some matchers that would otherwise require iterating over all elements.

The example you provide is one such method. Compare the two methods that determine the size of the actual value:

```
protected Integer featureValueOf(Iterable<E> actual) {
  int size = 0;
  for (Iterator<E> iterator = actual.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); iterator.next()) {
    size++;
  }
  return size;
}
```

versus

```
protected Integer featureValueOf(Collection<? extends E> actual) {
  return actual.size();
}
```

As long as the implementation of `size` doesn't itself iterate over all the elements, the latter will be much faster.

Comment: So, it is just for performance. I don't understand why they did not verified that the received Iterable was an instanceof Collection then! It was much more clean